# Whats the difference between React-Query and Redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-query

Am already using redux in my application.My application is kinda big (a lot of code ) and mostly using class base components. Should i go for react-query for better api calls. I have read online about the react-query and redux is suggested as an alternative to redux. Should i use react-query or not ?

Comment: Check https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/guides/does-this-replace-client-state

Comment: One manages asynchronous data fetches (React-Query) while the other is a state management library with determinant synchronous state updates using a publish/subscribe design pattern. These are two completely different types of libraries for two completely different use cases. They are not really comparable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already using Redux in your application and want to leverage the benefits of React Query, Redux Toolkit Query (RTK Query) is an excellent choice. RTK Query is part of the Redux Toolkit ecosystem and integrates seamlessly with Redux. It provides a powerful and flexible data fetching and caching solution while leveraging the existing Redux store for state management.